# Where is my Py_NoneStruct symbol (python, boost.python)?

Tags: python, c++, windows, boost-python, msvc12

I'm trying to compile a simple `main.cpp` which just includes `boost/python.hpp`.

Like the following:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using MSVC command line tools from my `git-bash` shell. I know that `cl.exe` need some environment variable that can be found in `vcvars32.bat`.

Here is how I'm compiling/linking my `main.cpp`:

```
# Since I'm using git-bash, I can use '-' instead of '/' for options, also
# `clwrap` is a tiny script that runs vcvars32.bat and forward arguments to `cl.exe`
# `python27.lib` and the boost.python lib are automatically autolink
$ clwrap -MD -I/c/Python27/include -I$BOOST_ROOT main.cpp -link -LIBPATH:"C:\\Python27\\libs" -LIBPATH:"C:\\Users\\Charly\\works\\cpp\\boost_1_57_0\\stage\\lib"
```

When I'm doing this, this ends up with a linking error:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___Py_NoneStruct referenced in function "public: __thiscall boost::python::api::object::object(void)" (??0object@api@python@boost@@QAE@XZ)
```

So, I decide to check my `python27.lib` file to see if the missing symbol is here:

```
$ nm /c/Python27/libs/python27.lib  | grep Py_None
```

NOTHING!!

But, the symbol is in my `libpython27.a`:

```
$ nm /c/Python27/libs/libpython27.a  | grep Py_None
00000000 I __imp__Py_NoneStruct
00000000 T _Py_NoneStruct
```

I did install `python` using the `.msi` installer (64bits). I built `boost.python` with the good `address-model=64`. Here is my CLI for building `boost.python`:

```
.\bootstrap.bat
.\b2 --with-python --build-type=complete address-model=64 variant=release link=shared toolset=msvc
```

Did I miss something? Is the `python` installer buggy? (I've found an [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue20785) about something similar)...

To be honest, I've tried many things, also I'm not really used to Windows development environment, so maybe I've missed something!

Thanks!

Comment: Because of C/C++ runtime issues, you have to use the same version of the MS compiler that was used to compile the Python interpreter itself (or use a another brand of compiler altogether). For Python 2.7, I believe it's Visual Studio 2008 (or nowadays the special [Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) since the latter is no longer available).

Comment: Well.. Finally, this was even simpler. I was using a 32bits compiler instead of a 64bits one. Now I'm facing another problem, but this is not related to that one and maybe your comment will help figuring it out! Big thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Fix my problem by using a proper 64 bits compiler.

If you take a look at the question you will see that my `clwrap` is using `vcvars32.bat`. Also, it uses `cl.exe` (32 bits version) which is here on my system:

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\bin\\cl.exe
```

But I've found another version of the compiler here:

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\bin\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe
```

Altogether with its needed `.bat` script:

```
C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\\VC\\bin\\x86_amd64\\vcvarsx86_amd64.bat
```

I did install some other packages for my VS. I don't know if this compiler came with those packages, but just in case, here are the [packages](http://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=40784).

Hope this helps!

Comment: For English speakers, here are the [packages](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784).